# complex transformation in apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am checking if we can use apache beam for our data pipeline. For example, we need to do the below sort of complex transformation and data summary. right now we do in pandas python:

```
dd_merged_f['group_id'] = dd_merged_f.assign(key=dd_merged_f['record_type'].eq('START').astype(int)).groupby(merge_cols)['key'].cumsum()
```

Just wondering if we can do this sort of code using PTransform? we should do a number of joins too.

Comment: Would you be able to describe your transformation needs in an update to the post that isn't expressed in Python?  My thinking is that if we understand the intent, we might be able to spot a beam architecture story that maps nicely which can *then* be implemented in either Python or Java.

Comment: @Kolban https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876003/add-a-unique-identifier-in-a-new-column-until-a-condition-met-on-another-column

Comment: Sorry my friend, I don't know what a "dask dataframe" is either.  I like to think that I have some skills in Apache Beam using Java (and some Python).  My hope was that you could describe the algorithm / function that you wanted to achieve using Apache Beam without reference to existing code or concepts that are generic or abstract in nature.

Comment: @Kolban Just see the two tables that I have in that question! Can I get the second table with added column name group id?